# How to cofigure Spring Jta Transaction?

Tags: spring, transactions, distributed-transactions, spring-transactions, transactional

Can somebody Help me with this error?
Or specific sample code for how to use JTA Transactionmanager?

I'm Using multi Databases, Main Database is defined in Xml with Transactionmanager, 
and rest DB is created with GenericApplicationContext in java file.

JtaTransactionManager setting in xml is like this

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" autowire="constructor">
   </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And Error Code ..

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: what application server are you using? a JEE one or Tomcat/Jetty?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat for server.

Comment: and when do you get this error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JTA transaction manager, you need:
1. a web server support JTA, like JBoss, Weblogic.
2. or an implementation of JTA lib, like atomikos.

So in your circumstance(using tomcat), you  should use a JTA implementation lib. If you use spring-boot, you just add it in pom, like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And, you don't need to do anything in your configuration if you use spring boot.

But, you need to wrap your dataSource with `XADataSourceWrapper`. You can just autowire this property and use `xaDataSourceWrapper.wrapDataSource()` to make you datasource a XA datasource.